# best pattern design for my project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create a solution in asp.net web form and database first entity and want to create web application at first but in the future, I need create web service for using in android app.

so I need a design pattern for my project that my web service project doesn't have a dependency on my web project.

I know probably should use n tier but I need someone explain it.

---

i need someone say which and why use pattern for compare

Comment: This is too broad, but you just need to move everything that those two projects depend on, into a separate project. That's it... So if Web service and website use the same models, then you move them into a separate project `YourProject.Models`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest for webservice part you make use of `WebApi` as its easy to create and later on you can use with you android mobile app also.

WEBAPI is helpuful for Rest implementation and you cna use it very easily.

your project structure needs to be like

- Asp.NEt -- fornt end

  - in this you can make use of MVP(model-view-Prsenter) or MVC(model-view-controller)
- Business layer consist of Business classes (Modle classes) and encapsulate you full business logic and business rules
- Data Layer - here you make call to WebAPI functions which will do work of database interaction ...in WebAPI you can again implemnt three layer 
  or 
  You can create DataLayer library whih you can make use in WebProject as well as in you WebAPI project ...

Comment: you mean use bll and dal layers and call bll method from web project or web api?

Comment: @MajidDehnamaki- call webapi from dal as webapi is going to be you datasoruce for getting data ...

Comment: can give me some reference for doing this?